# Removing AWS EventBrigde Constant Input for Lambda Function logs

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-event-bridge

I have a lamba function running performing application checks. This function is triggered every 10 mins and the app details are send as Json format Constant Input.
Is their a way in AWS, that these input could not be logged in the CloudWatch log groups?

I tried to use the File pattern feature of Lambda, but not able to find the exact pattern to exclude these json inputs.